# WPF: Conditionally Format TextBox if Property on Model is True

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a textbox on a window, which shows a currency value. The textbox has a binding for it's IsReadOnly property to a property on the datacontext. If the textbox is in readonly mode, I want to format the text within it as a currency value, with a £ symbol and commas for the thousand separator, but if it is in edit mode, I want it to be a straight up number.

The StringFormat property doesn't seem to be an option because it's unconditional. The Converter property seems like a hopeful candidate but I'd need to pass the IsReadOnly property as the ConverterParameter, and ConvereterParameter doesn't seem to want to be bound.

What's the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `TextBox.Text` binding based on Trigger, in this case `IsReadOnly=True` to use `StringFormat`

```
<TextBox ...>
   <TextBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
           <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=MyDecimal}"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=MyDecimal, StringFormat=C2}"/>
               </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Perfect. That works just fine - the only snag is I have to do this with about 50 textboxes bound to properties with different names. Do you know of any way to make the "MyDecimal" part of this style variable if I were to abstract it out into a reusable style?

Comment: One way would be to create some proxy attached property for `TextBox` and  bind `TextBox.Text` not to `MyDecimal` but to this property and from outside instead of binding to `Text` bind same attached property